# Passing object pointer as pointer to base class

Tags: c++

Is this code legal?

It crashes and I'm not sure if it's because of my programming environment (it's an embedded device) or because I've written dodgy code.

```
int foo(NGKGame * game) {
    game->init(); //Crashes here
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    NGKGame * game = new PlaneGame();
    game->init(); //This call is okay
    foo(game); 

    return 0;
}
```

`NGKGame` is the base class. `PlaneGame` is a derived class from `NGKGame`. `init()` is a pure virtual function in the base class but is implemented in `PlaneGame`.

Thanks,

**Edit:**

The init function being called twice is just as part of the example. In my current implementation, it's empty.

Comment: Could you check the addresses of `game` and `init` in the both cases? Are they same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your snippet.

Though are you meant to call `NGKGame::init` twice or is it just part of your example code? My hunch is that something inside `PlaneGame::init` is malfunctioning when calling it again, if that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably crashing because you are calling `init()` twice on the same object.  Since you didn't show us the source code of `init()` I can't speculate on why it would crash, but it seems like a function named `init` should only be called once.

If you want a better answer, please see http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

This code is fine - assuming its OK for you to call `init()` twice.

That `init()` is PV in `NGKGame` is not a problem. The whole point of PVs is to allow you to call them in the manner of `foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine. It *might* have to do with some compiler flags. I had a somewhat similar issue a while ago. A code which juggles around pointers, would work fine with no optimization flags (using gcc), but would crash with the -O3(optimization) turned on. I did not figure out how to get rid of that, so I just manually added various optimization flags that were enabled with -O3 and it worked fine.